# Code Analysis broken in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

OS: Vista 32 bit
IDE: Visual Studio 2010
I was using VS this morning, and when I came back from lunch intellisense/code analysis are completely broken. If I create a WPF project, add a new class definition, and in that class put, for example

```
    int foo = 5;
    foo = 6;
```

Intellisense won't have been able to tab complete "foo" (it won't have shown up) and if I type it myself then I'll get compiler errors saying "Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" and "'WpfApplication2.Class1.foo' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'"

Note that if I tried the same code in the codebehind for the MainWindow.xaml this will work as expected.

Further testing shows the same behavior in added classes for console application projects, but not in their autogenerated file, Program.cs.

I've tried devenv /ResetSettings and resetting settings through the import/export tool, and it makes no difference. I've deleted the VS files in the documents folder, Appdata/roaming, and /local, with no effect. I'm in a corporate environment, so getting my hands on the install media to do a reinstall is a rather large ordeal, if possible I'd like to fix this.

Comment: Lock your workstation during lunch. ;)

Comment: What does this have to do with "code analysis" (FxCop)?

Comment: Because it's the code analysis that throws the errors at compile time, or at least that's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you might have mismatched curly brackets.  { }

Comment: I don't think that's it. this is still evident in even the simplest class file possible, I can literally just right click, "add-> class" and leave everything default, type that code snippet into the class (two open brackets, two close ones, I counted) and hit f5 and blow those two errors, this is on a Console or WPF application with all default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, weird, I still don't know what caused it, but it seems deleting everything and doing /ResetSettings fixed it. Magic?